# Extract parent component configuration from number/types/props of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a best-practices way to derive configuration information for a parent component from its children in React? Take the case of a wizard component that requires stepping through some number of steps. You'd imagine that the API for such a component might look something like this:

```js
<Wizard>
  <Wizard.Step id="step-1" title="It's step 1!">
    Step 1
  </Wizard.Step>
  <Wizard.Step id="step-2" title="It's step 2!">
    Step 2
  </Wizard.Step>
</Wizard>
```

In the example above, if you wanted the wizard to navigate from step 1 to step 2, the wizard would need to have some way of knowing that it has two steps, and that step 1 comes before step 2. I've got something working using `React.Children.toArray` that iterates over each child and reads the props like so:

```js
const steps = React.Children.toArray(children).map(child => {
  const { id, title } = child.props;
  return { id, title };
});
```

This falls apart under more complicated circumstances where components are nested. In the example of the wizard component, you might want to group some steps under the same heading like this:

```js
<Wizard>
  <Wizard.Heading title="It's steps 1 and 2!">
    <Wizard.Step id="step-1">
      Step 1
    </Wizard.Step>
    <Wizard.Step id="step-2">
      Step 2
    </Wizard.Step>
  </Wizard.Heading>
  <Wizard.Heading title="It's steps 3 and 4!">
    <Wizard.Step id="step-1">
      Step 1
    </Wizard.Step>
    <Wizard.Step id="step-2">
      Step 2
    </Wizard.Step>
  </Wizard.Heading>
</Wizard>
```

I feel like my previous solution fails apart here. If you try and build a list of steps using the previous method (using `React.Children.map` or `React.Children.toArray`) such that the wizard knows step 2 needs to go to step 3, you run in to the issue of the `<Wizard.Step />` components updating and the `<Wizard />` component not knowing that such a thing has happened.

What's the recommended approach to doing so? I can think of a couple that might work (ie: having `<Wizard.Heading />` build a list of steps, and then have `<Wizard />` build a list of steps from just the headings) but I'm not sure what approach to use that would stay within the bounds of how React is intended to be used.

Alternatively, is this the wrong approach to the problem? Should I just be using a large configuration object to tell the wizard how it should structure itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a question regarding ReactJS programming paradigms I won't be pasting code here. But the general idea is this:

Props are for dataflow downwards and functions for dataflow upwards through the Component Heirarchy. So if you want some metadata about your Children Components without knowing what form your Children Components could take, you need to pass a function to them that will access your Parent's state.

I would recommend writing an [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (specifically [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-pass-unrelated-props-through-to-the-wrapped-component)) that would wrap your Child Components and pass some additional functions to them which would collect and send up metadata through the HOC to your Parent Component.

Another thing to keep in mind is [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which could also be used in this scenario, where each Child would append to the context on ComponentDidMount but context comes with it's own set of [issues](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats) and should generally be avoided unless necessary.

Comment: If this seems too vague I can illustrate with some examples perhaps but that will take me some time since it's a fairly complicated use-case.

Comment: In the end, I took inspiration from both and used context to pass additional functions down to each child component to register with parent component. It appears that I can rely on the fact that sibling components mount and update in the order they're declared in the parent component.

Comment: That's great! It's always nice to hear when a complicated problem is solved using one's help. As for relying on the order of mounting and updating ofsibling components, I would advise against it. maybe right now they do so but once your application becomes larger with perhaps some API calls in the constructor or componentWillMount, the order **might** change, and cause buggy behaviour. Though I'm not sure exactly how you're using this info so maybe I'm wrong, just be careful while relying on orders/timings of events/actions while working with JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to find a way to properly determine the order of sibling components and not having much luck, but I feel that's a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be a single object, which represents a wizard - and a component which renders the wizard, it's steps, and anything else you might want to show (such as a header).

In addition to the config of the wizard, you'll also want to have somewhere for the data which you expect to populate from the wizard.

You'll want to think of everything that your wizard should show on different steps. Inputs, text, images, etc.

```
const wizard = {
currentStep = 1,
  data: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    address: '',
},
steps: [
  {
    title: "Basic info",
    inputs: [
      {name: "Username", type: "text", required},
      {name: "Password", type: "password", required},
      {name: "Address", type: "text", required}
     ],
    }
  ]
}
```

You would have a wizard, which takes the steps, adds a few common components to them (such as adding a back / next button) as well as stores all of the input data into the object.

```
<Wizard>
  <Wizard.Step id="step-1" title="It's step 1!">
    Step 1
  </Wizard.Step>
  <Wizard.Step id="step-2" title="It's step 2!">
    Step 2
  </Wizard.Step>
</Wizard>
```

The mistake here is that you are trying to render both steps at once. Don't. Just have a wizard which knows what step it is on, and then pass the step object to the wizardStep component. The wizard controls which step is visible, and keeps track of it in the state.